# How to expose WSS 'secure websocket' with Java

Tags: java, websocket, jboss, java-websocket

I'm setting up a new webSocket server using Java, and want to expose it in WSS because my client side app is in HTTPS. Could you help me please

I've tried to modify my web.xml but dosen't work

```xml
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Protected resource</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <!-- https -->
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

This is my EndPoint Class

```java
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/signalisation/{username}", decoders = MessageDecoder.class, encoders = MessageEncoder.class)
public class ChatEndpoint {
    private Session session;
    private static final Set<ChatEndpoint> chatEndpoints = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();
    private static HashMap<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("username") String username) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        System.out.println("connected");
        this.session = session;
        chatEndpoints.add(this);
        users.put(session.getId(), username);

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setFrom(username);
        message.setContent("Connected!");
        broadcast(message, message.getTo());
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, Message message) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        message.setFrom(users.get(session.getId()));
        System.out.println("messaged");

    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        System.out.println("out");
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable throwable) {
        // Do error handling here
    }

    private static void broadcast(Message message, String id) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        chatEndpoints.forEach(endpoint -> {
            if (endpoint.session.getId().equals(id)){
                synchronized (endpoint) {
                    try {
                        endpoint.session.getBasicRemote()
                                .sendObject(message);
                    } catch (IOException | EncodeException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public String getKeyFromMap(HashMap map, String value){

        for (Object o : map.keySet()) {
            if (map.get(o).equals(value))
                return o.toString();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

My Client Side app

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://<IP_ADRESSE>:8080/<PATH>/signalisation/'+c);
conn.onopen = function () {
      console.log("Connected to the server");
};
```

My actual result is :

client.js:11 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://IP_ADRESSE:PORT/?user=blabla' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://IP_ADRESSE:8080/PATH/signalisation/blabla'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.

Answer (score 0):

It was some month ago, but hope it helps someone with the same error.
Change `ws://` to `wss://` on the client side app, just before `IP_ADRESSE`.